# Custom Data Provider with bucketed items

Tags: integration, data-provider

I am creating a custom data provider to integration news articles from an external API into a Sitecore solution.

The external data source has a large amount of news articles though, so I would like to bucket the items in the Sitecore content tree.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: And you're sure you want to source this content via a Data Provider?  as opposed to say; an integration run - importing the content on a schedule?

Comment: What would the benefit be over Data Provider (except for taking the load off the external API)? From what i have read on the topic, Sitecore should not be used as a data store for external data.

Comment: Is there any way you can logically split the news articles up from your external API?

e.g. Can you page the results? Or get them by date etc?

Comment: Yes, the API supports paging and search by a range of different criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your root item (probably a real Sitecore item) has to be set as a bucket. For your child items (the virtual ones from your provider), you need to set the `Is Bucketable` value to `true` on the 'Standard Values' of the template (so not on the template itself).

Definitively read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692431/display-items-in-bucket-with-sitecore-data-provider as well as it covers your question.